# How to create multiple images before a program is run and draw them individually outside of the image.onload() function?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to draw hundreds of images onto a canvas, but only when I reference the specific image variable. I encountered a function created by someone responding to another one of these posts that I was using. It was something like `map = createImage("images/Global/Map.png")` and it would return the value I was able to draw like this: `ctx.drawImage(map, 0, 0, 224, 292)` instead of me having to do it in the onload function.
I guess what I am trying to ask is how would I create an object that would allow me to do this?

I tried something along the line of this:

```
const createImage = function(src) {
  image = newImage();
  image.src = src;
  image.onload = function() {
    return(image);
  }
}

// Other code creating images...
var map = createImage("images/map.png");

// Code to draw map
ctx.drawImage(map, 0, 0, 224, 292);
```

Thanks in advance. I'm hoping its a simple problem.

Comment: `"how would I create an object that would allow me to do this?"`- do what precisely? And  `" but only when I reference the specific image variable"` - how are you referencing this image variable?This is not particularly clear at present - please provide sufficent HTML and Javascript to properly illustrate the problem

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius The HTML would be irrelevant, because I am not creating any elements in the HTML code outside of the canvas. The reference to the image variable is specifically the name of the var created to hold the info of the image 'map'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was an idiot and should not have been allowed to post this question.
I was trying to do animations using canvas on javascript.

The thing that would have solved my problem (while it was never a problem to begin with) was the `window.requestAnimationFrame(function())`. As it kept animating, sooner or later the images would load and be drawn. To my eyes, it appeared as if it were instant, hence my wanting the program to wait until everything was loaded.

There was never a problem to begin with. Oops.